# Node.js/Express: Read XML Post, Amazon IPN

Tags: xml, node.js

I want to use Amazon's IPN. So far i never worked with XML and just accessed POST params with `req.body.param`. This does not seem to work at all.

Amazon sends a post request structured like this:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
x-amz-sns-message-type: Notification
x-amz-sns-message-id: 0000000-0000-00000-0000-00000EXAMPLE
x-amz-sns-topic-arn: arn:aws:sns:EXAMPLE:11111EXAMPLE:TestTopic
x-amz-sns-subscription-arn: arn:aws:sns:EXAMPLE:11111EXAMPLE:TestTopic: EXAMPLE
Content-Length: 999
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Host: ec2-EXAMPLE.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Amazon Simple Notification Service Agent
{
    Type : Notification,
    MessageId : xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxEXAMPLE,
    TopicArn : arn:aws:sns:EXAMPLE:11111EXAMPLE:TestTopic,
    Message :
    {
        NotificationReferenceId: 1111111-1111-11111-1111-11111EXAMPLE,
        NotificationType: OrderReferenceNotification,
        SellerId: A3PJMS5WFYSRB4,
        ReleaseEnvironment: Sandbox,
        Version: 2013-01-01,
        NotificationData:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <OrderReferenceNotification xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/ipn/OffAmazonPayments/2013-01-01">
                <OrderReference>
                    <AmazonOrderReferenceId>P01-0000000-0000000-000000</AmazonOrderReferenceId>
                    <OrderTotal>
                        <Amount>0.0</Amount>
                        <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    </OrderTotal>
                    <SellerOrderAttributes />
                    <OrderReferenceStatus>
                        <State>Closed</State>           
                        <LastUpdateTimestamp>2013-01-01T01:01:01.001Z</LastUpdateTimestamp>
                        <ReasonCode>AmazonClosed</ReasonCode>
                    </OrderReferenceStatus>
                    <CreationTimestamp>2013-01-01T01:01:01.001Z</CreationTimestamp>       
                    <ExpirationTimestamp>2013-01-01T01:01:01.001Z</ExpirationTimestamp>
                </OrderReference>
            </OrderReferenceNotification>,
        Timestamp:2013-01-01T01:01:01Z
    }
    Timestamp : 2013-01-01T01:01:001Z,
    SignatureVersion : 1,
    Signature : rkne..9=kOUhF,
    SigningCertURL : https://sns.EXAMPLE.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-aaaaaabbbbbbccccccEXAMPLE.pem,
    UnsubscribeURL : https://sns.EXAMPLE.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:EXAMPLE:11111EXAMPLE:TestTopic:GUID
}
```

My routes.js for this routes is:

```
app.post('/approveDonationAmazon', (req, res) ->
    #receive payment result from paypal
    # update Database
    {parseString} = require 'xml2js'
    console.log "req",req
    console.log "reqbody",req.body
    console.log "raw body",req.rawBody
    if req.body.message?
      xml = req.body.message
      parseString xml, (err, result) ->
      console.dir "result",result

      #TODO Process Payment Callback
      # databaseService.approveDonation(db, payment_status, payer_email, mc_gross, (err) ->
      #   # if there is an error retrieving, send the error. nothing after res.json({ err: err }); will execute
      #   if (err)
      #     return res.json({ err: err })
      #   return true
      # )
    else
      return res.json({ err: 'no message received' })
  )
```

My server log tells me that my vars a basically not defined:

```
2015-05-04 12:57:18.149458500   _remoteAddress: '::1',
2015-05-04 12:57:18.149458500   body: {},
2015-05-04 12:57:18.149459500   route: 
2015-05-04 12:57:18.149459500    { path: '/approveDonationAmazon',
2015-05-04 12:57:18.149462500      stack: [ [Object] ],
2015-05-04 12:57:18.149462500      methods: { post: true } } }
2015-05-04 12:57:18.149462500 reqbody {}
2015-05-04 12:57:18.149463500 raw body undefined
```

**Question:**

How to access the message vars, e.g. SellerId or Amount?